# How to show image thumb from input type file without upload, or with

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to show image thumb from input type file without upload, or with
I need to create file preview, when user select file in input type=file, i found, that ajax don't support file upload, so - maybe it is possible to show thumbs _without_actual_upload_ in js? Jquery/simple js

Comment: Not possible. This amounts to reading the local file system, and that's a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's no current, cross-browser compatible method of getting the data from a file input.

You could use a hidden iframe as the target for upload, when the user selects a file, submit the form to the iframe window.  You could use the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) (since you tagged jQuery), which will create the hidden iframe for you if the form contains a file input.

Answer (score 0):

*Some* browsers implement [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), so you could use it for displaying the images. Using the File API together with some new features of the XMLHttpRequest objects, it's possible to upload files using ajax.
Other possibility is to upload the file with hidden iframe.